# Login Problem with Flutter Google Sign In ("Google hasn’t verified this app. The app is requesting access to sensitive info in your Google Account.")

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-signin, verification

I am trying to make an app using Flutter and get this message ("Google hasn’t verified this app
The app is requesting access to sensitive info in your Google Account.") when I try to login. How can I verify the app?

I've checked the OAuth consent screen on console.cloud.google.com. However it says verification not required. How can I verify my app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.